# Javascript fetch api, requested data type

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to cache certain file types using `Service Worker`, to do that I need to know if the fetch request is requesting an image, *CSS or javascript* file, if yes than cache the fetch result, if not then don't cache it.
The code is like this :

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', async e => {
  const req = e.request;
  const fresh = await fetch(req);
  // here i want to know if the above request is requesting a static file ex:css, js or images 
});
```

Comment: you can use `fresh.headers.get('content-type')`.

Comment: @RolandStarke it return null

Answer (score -1):

You could inspect the `.url` and/or the `.headers`  for the appropriate values. For the URL, you could look to see if it has a well-defined extension. For the headers, look for the `accept` header.